# Sum of the vectors from one vertex of a regular polygon to each remaining vertex

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, polygons

I'm attempting to calculate the sum of the vectors from one fixed vertex of a regular m-sided polygon to each of the other vertices. The center of the polygon is at (0,0).

It's for a study guide preceding my Linear Algebra exam tomorrow, and I'm entirely stumped by this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the fixed vertex be at $(1,0)$, given by position vector $v_0$, and all the other vertices be given by position vectors $v_1$...$v_{m-1}$

Then $\Sigma_{i=0}^{m-1}v_i=0$, since they will form a closed polygon.

Now the required sum is $$(v_0-v_0)+(v_1-v_0)+(v_2-v_0)+...+(v_{m-1}-v_0)$$

$$=-mv_0=\left(\begin{matrix}-m\\0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Oh, that absolutely makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Good luck with the exam!

Comment: How do we know that they will form a closed polygon?

Comment: @ScottEmmons since their sum is zero, they can be placed end to end to form a closed loop

Comment: @DavidQuinn Which do we conclude first, that the sum of the vectors from the center to each of the vertices of the polygon is zero, or that the vectors from the center to each of the vertices of the polygon can be placed end to end to form a closed loop? I see how one is true if and only if the other is true, but I do not see at which we arrive first based on the given information of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_m$ be the regular polygon's vertices and $O$ its centre.

Then the sum of the vectors from vertex $V_m$ to each of the other vertices is $$\vec{V_mV_1}+\vec{V_mV_2}+\ldots+\vec{V_mV_{m-1}}\\=
(m-1)\vec{V_mO}+(\vec{OV_1}+\vec{OV_2}+\ldots+\vec{OV_{m-1}})+(\vec{OV_m}-\vec{OV_m})\\=
m\vec{V_mO}+(\vec{OV_1}+\vec{OV_2}+\ldots+\vec{OV_m})\\=
m\vec{V_mO},$$ since, by symmetry, $(\vec{OV_1}+\vec{OV_2}+\ldots+\vec{OV_m})=\mathbf0.$